# What to name variables in php to post data using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having difficulty creating a simple form that is to take a user's inputted email address and store it in a server side .log file.

HTML & JQuery in index.php:

```
<div>
  <form id="form" method="post" action="">
    <input name="field1" type="Your Email" id="field1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Sign me up!" id="submitme">
  </form>
</div>

<script>
$("#submitme").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_data = $("#form").serialize()
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    url: 'action_page.php',
  });
});
</script>
```

My PHP in action_page.php: (that is to take the data posted and save it into the .log)

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['form_data'])) { 
        $txt=$_POST['form_data']; 
        file_put_contents('test.log',$txt."\n",FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
        exit();
    }
?>
```

After clicking the submit button, the page only refreshes and nothing is added to my .log file. I feel like the problem is something to do with the way I reference the data in my ajax function and in my action_page.php. I've tried all the different ways I've seen it done in various stackoverflow posts but I can't seem to find the right way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: want to make it simple, jsut skip the ajax

Comment: Did you include jquery? Any errors thrown?

Comment: @chris85 Variable naming!

Comment: @Jan Variable naming.

Comment: @PraveenKumar shouldn't the `event.preventDefault` stop the form from processing so the page shouldn't refresh?

Comment: @chris85 Yes, it is right. So that form doesn't submit in the traditional method, but it submits through AJAX call in the next step. `:)`

Comment: I should also tell to the OP that: *"You won't be able to see the output in the screen but it gets written in the file. You can check the response by seeing the Console Window."*

Comment: @PraveenKumar OP says the page refreshes though which sounds like the  JS isn't executing.

Comment: @Dagon Wanna make it more simpler, skip the server, use the notepad. Man, he's trying to learn AJAX and jQuery, why are you demotivating?

Comment: @chris85 Thanks, I didn't make a note of it. Lemme update my answer.

Comment: because you should always learn the basics first @PraveenKumar

Comment: @Dagon In the basics of "AJAX with jQuery" - Where does it say you not to use `$.ajax()`, kindly let me know...

Comment: @Dagon Let's solve the OP's problem. If we don't know, it is better we don't speak. `:)` Agree? Even if he is not using AJAX, jQuery, it will never work, because of the naming variables.

Comment: since when did form submitting require ajax at all?

Comment: @Dagon I am specifically saying about "AJAX with jQuery". Kindly answer my question. *Even if he is not using AJAX, jQuery, it will never work, because of the variables accessing. Right?*

Comment: @Dagon Read my answer first and try to appreciate others' work. Don't stay in the olden days, no AJAX, no Chrome, using IE 5 and Windows 95! Duh!

Comment: @sharma0611 I believe you have read the [tour] and know how to respond. I cannot find you even online. You get answers instantly and when you post a question (a very simple one) and leave it off, it tends to create fury among other users. See the above discussion!

Comment: Hey guys, so the reason I'm using Ajax in this submission process is because I later want to be able for users to stay on the same page after submitting their email and perhaps add a .success func that'll allow me to add in a little animated "Thanks". Please advise if Ajax is not the right route to go with in accomplishing this goal. 

Also sorry for the late response, didn't think I'd get replies this fast! Thanks guys!

Comment: The value of the type attribute on the `input` element is not valid.

Comment: It works now with the original code I had + Stryner's object edit

Answer (score 1):

The `form_data` goes this way, `field1=value`. It takes the individual `<input>`'s `name` as the `POST`'s key, so what you need to do in the PHP file is:

```
<?php
    if (count($_POST) && !empty($_POST['field1'])) {
      $txt = $_POST['field1'];
      file_put_contents('test.log', $txt . "\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
      exit();
    }
?>
```

Also, I am checking for `!empty()` rather than `isset()` because it would definitely be set. And also checking for `$_POST`'s count, will ensure that this runs only in `POST` method.

**Update**

> ***Note:*** You won't be able to see the output in the screen but it gets written in the file. You can check the response by seeing the Console Window.

I just saw that you get your page refreshed. May be, you forgot to include jQuery library? You need to check the console for errors, and it should really say:

```
$ is not a function.
```

So to solve that, kindly add jQuery library by adding this code before your `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know, if it works. Check your console for errors too.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing any variable called `form_data`. You're passing: `data: form_data`, which is in the form `key=value&key2=value2`.

One solution is to pass it in a new object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        form_data: form_data
    },
    url: 'action_page.php',
});
```